# Winrepo not working correctly

Tags: salt-stack

I have a number of packages that I need to deploy to window 10 machines. When trying to install a single package with:

```
sudo salt <minion name> pkg.install <program> version=xxx
```

Instead of the program being installed normally, a run command is generated and needs to be manually run to install the program.

I tried running:

```
sudo salt-run winrepo.update_git_repos
```

But I receive the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/grains/core.py:1493: DeprecationWarning: The "osmajorrelease" will be a type of an integer.
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/runners/winrepo.py:174: DeprecationWarning: The 'win_repo' config option is deprecated, please use 'winrepo_dir' instead.
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/runners/winrepo.py:210: DeprecationWarning: winrepo git support now requires either GitPython or pygit2. Please install either GitPython >= 0.3 (or pygit2 >= 0.20.3 with libgit2 >= 0.20.0), clear out /srv/salt/win/repo, and restart the salt-master service.
Exception occurred in runner winrepo.update_git_repos: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/client/mixins.py", line 356, in low
data['return'] = self.functions[fun](*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/runners/winrepo.py", line 248, in update_git_repos
result = mminion.states['git.latest'](remote_url,
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1055, in __getitem__
func = super(LazyLoader, self).__getitem__(item)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/utils/lazy.py", line 93, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'git.latest'
```

I've tried refreshing the db but it doesn't seem to help. I also tried the following command with a similar results:

```
  sudo salt-run winrepo.genrepo
```

When trying to simply deploy my sls file for the programs I want installed, with the command:

```
sudo salt 'ds' state.apply <sls file>
```

I get the error:

```
Too many functions declared in state '*' in SLS 'stingray-setup-Win10'
```

My sls file looks like this:

```
base:
  '*':
    - windows.states.<some program>
    - windows.states.<some program>
    -.....
```

I think the issue lies somewhere with winrepo. I tried installing GitPython and restarting the master with no luck.

Comment: Still the same issue as in the other question? How does your salt setup looks like. Where is your master (virtual or real box) - where is your desired minion? How they are connected to each other and regarding the commands listed above - which of those commands was executed where (minion or master)?

Comment: @dahrens Ya. Your answer from the last question was the correct one but I think the issue lied with winrepo not working as it should. My master I believe is virtual, as are the VM's. The master runs CENTOS and minions are on Windows 10. All commands are executed on the master.

Comment: ya the one about the GitPython and winrepo needing to be winrepodir right. I've been trying to find a solution to that to no avail. I installed gitpython but saw no change.

Comment: also added the line of text: winrepo_dir: /srv/salt/win/repo to the master.conf file located /etc/salt/master.d but nothing sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this message hidden in your stacktrace:

> winrepo git support now requires either GitPython or pygit2. Please install either GitPython >= 0.3 (or pygit2 >= 0.20.3 with libgit2 >= 0.20.0), clear out /srv/salt/win/repo, and restart the salt-master service.

Check if one of the libraries is present, if not install it using either `pip` or OS packages and clear `/srv/salt/win/repo` afterwards as mentioned. Don't forget to restart the salt-master afterwards.

Comment: by clearing the directory indicate does it mean removing everything within it? Cause thats were my folders are for program init files

Comment: uhm - you wrote them yourself? i throught you want to access the already written ones. `salt-run winrepo.update_git_repos` loads information from external source which include a lot of already bundled sls files for windows. i would advice you to backup your states somewhere else and try to get the prepared stuff working first.

Comment: well i never wrote them. I am just taking over someone who setup saltstack and kinda just left it in an usuable position. But ya your probably right i can just back them up and revert if it doesnt work

Comment: didnt seem to work. going to try with pygit2 but im getting more errors trying to install that too haha.

Comment: one of the errors that maybe might be the root cause is The 'win_repo' config option is deprecated, please use 'winrepo_dir' instead. But I cant really find much on it online. Any ideas?

Comment: right now i have no clue - forget about `pygit2` - you currently need to compile it - and `gitpython` should also work. I need to dig into that topic the next days at work - will ping back if I have a deeper understanding of those _[for me still magic]_ windows states.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help